# What is the idiomatic way to convert &i64 into &[u8; 8]?

Tags: rust, slice

I'm doing some hashing with [blake2](https://docs.rs/blake2/0.8.1/blake2/index.html) crate. It only accepts slices of bytes `&[u8]`. Largest part of the data (String) can be casted into slice of bytes without any problems, but timestamp (i64) can't be. Is there a cross-platform, idiomatic way of doing such a conversion? Endianness of i64 is ensured by calling `to_le` before doing anything with it.

Comment: Do you actually need it to be a reference? Since these are copy types, you might as well get a `[u8; 8]` from an `i64`, for which there is [`to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.to_le_bytes).

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ouch. Last time i checked that page there was no such method. This will do, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `i64` type has a [`to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.to_le_bytes) method that returns `[u8; 8]`, and since `i64` is a copy type, it's easy to call that and then pass a reference to the returned array. It won't be a reference to the same bytes as the original `i64` since it returns an owned array and not a reference, but that shouldn't matter in this case.